# Bad request error before doing anything

Tags: jquery, html, dotnetnuke, 2sxc

I just installed 2sxc 8.9 on a website. Installation was done in about 20 seconds.
Then I tried to make an app and add content-type and data.

Than I tried to make a view but it's giving this error:

[image]

It's on DNN 7.4 which is supposed to work, right?

I also tried 2sxc 8.6 but that one is not working either.

What is going on?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The Content-Type mentioned above is an internal content-type needed to store template configuration.

It's not normal to be missing this, as it is added 100% automatically during installation. My best guess is that you had some kind of interrupted installation, but that for some reason (maybe forced re-install without un-install first) it got to a point believing that the installation had worked.

My recommendation: un-install the module and install again, you should be good to go.